# Is there a way in Cartodb.js to include an autcomplete search bar?

Tags: carto, carto-js, search

I am using the code below to add a search bar to my mapping application, is there a way to include an autocomplete search bar? Something that would provide suggestions based on what the user is typing?

```
//add search bar to map     
var v = cdb.vis.Overlay.create('search', map.viz, {})
v.show();
$('#map').append(v.render().el);
$('.cartodb-searchbox').find('input.text').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Location...');
```

I would like to use something that does not point back to my datasets but points to something like google's geocoder, bing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've just made this example: http://bl.ocks.org/juanignaciosl/7b6f75a4edf875f8a778 (by joining http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/7932459 with http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/befa66fc9327f6c2908e).

Comment: is there a way to not rely on your own data - i.e. use something like google geocoder?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of incorporating an autocomplete google geocoder based search bar in a cartodb viz [here](https://github.com/MassGIS/AutoCompleteWithDropPin).